# Stop scrolling UITableView perfectly on cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a list of cells of varying height, and I want the scroll to top perfectly at the top of a cell.

For this I can use

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
```

And I can set the targetContentOffset to the top of a cells frame.

However if cells yet to be laid out have a height different from their estimated height, then this destination cells origin will change, and I don't get a chance to account for this.

Is there anyway to land perfectly on a cell after a scroll when the origin can change?